# iOS Non-renewing restoration

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

My iOS app new version was just accepted by Apple, but they sent me an email to ask me to make a subscription restoration button.

But in conditions it's written `If your app uses non-renewing subscriptions, your app is responsible for the restoration process.` so I guess there isn't restoration button for non-renewing subscriptions.

My app doesn't have account system, so I'm saving the subscription expiration date in iCloud default store.

How can I do to restore the subscription without this iCloud account ?

Comment: As far as I know from Non-consumable In-App Purchase, restoration might be a part of fresh install when you don't have subscription expiration date being stored iCloud default store.

Comment: I saw that the receipt is deprecated on the last versions, so if I save the subscription in NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore, users can retrieve their subscription on other devices ?

Comment: You might consider the restoration process over reading iCloud default store on a new device. Just propose to restore purchases and rely on what App Store would return to your app in payment queue.

Comment: I don't see any way for the appstore to return the subscription expiration date I defined myself